# Cross platform service (Connect to java service through c# client)

Tags: c#, java, reflection, wsdl, cross-platform

I have a server application in Java which has two simple operations, addTwoInts and multiplyTwoFloats. I'm trying to implement these math services through a C# client application. I should be able to use reflection to invoke the operations included in a WSDL that the client receives from the server. I am more familiar with the Java side than with the C# side - how should I approach this from the client side, assuming my server already properly serves a WSDL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a webservice from your C# project using the WSDL.  There is a wizard in VS that comes up when you create new webservice reference.

### Edit

For the url in the wizard just set the WSDL file you have VS will show you visually what the available functions are and create the stubs for you.

Comment: Thanks, that should get me off to at least a fair start. :)